# Socket.io disconnect not firing when accessed through an Apache proxy

Tags: javascript, apache, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a simple socket.io express server and connect to it through an apache vhost proxy on port 80. The express server runs on port 3456, but the network where we test from blocks traffic out, and the network the express server is hosted on blocks traffic in. (for ports not whitelisted)

This is primarily meant to help a proof of concept for the project, in an early prototyping phase.

Working my way around the ports, I've set up a vhost on the server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.test.company.com
    ServerAlias www.project.test.company.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3456/
</VirtualHost>
```

Project.test.company.com would be the URL used with "project" and "company" replaced.

This works as I had hoped, forwarding traffic to the vhost to the express server avoiding the blocked ports problems. However, when closing the browser / client connected, it takes a little over a minute before the disconnect occurs on the server. I'm guessing some sort of timeout triggers. When talking directly to :3456 instead of the vhost (accessing it locally through a vpn), the disconnect happens instantly. The disconnect works as expected if an actual close/disconnect is done by the client instead of closing the browser.

Could the vhost be written differently to not have this quirk?

To reproduce the problem, here's a basic functional version of the code used.

Server index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3456);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

var users = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('* Client joined: ' + socket.id);
    users.push(socket.id);
    io.emit('users', users);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('* Client disconnect: ' + socket.id);
        users = users.filter((user) => {
            return user !== socket.id;
        });
        io.emit('users', users);
    });
});
```

client.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users</h1>

    <div id="main">
        <div v-for="user in users">
            <span>{{ user }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var socket = io();

        new Vue({
            el: '#main',

            data: {
                users: []
            },

            mounted: function() {
                socket.on('users', (users) => {
                    this.users = users;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try it with https ?

Comment: No, we don't have https enabled on the server, so I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I just posted a similar question.

Comment: Sadly no, I moved to Laravel with pusher instead of node with socket.io for backends with websockets.